# Spyder ver. 2.3.8 from default repo doesn't work in 16.10 but Spyder 3.0.1 does, not in repo

Tags: 16.10, spyder

As I understand it, Debian removed the qt4 webkit and in 16.10 that affects the versions of the python spyder IDE in the default repos. However, while Spyder 3.0.1 will launch, there are three missing dependencies.

In short: Does anybody know what the heck is going on and when it will be addressed in full?